# Problem returning entity grouped with LINQ in HTTP GET

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, http-get

What I'm doing wrong in this method below? I created a group with linq because I need to group the list by 2 columns and for this grouping I will have a list of files.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("versions-by-period")]
        public IActionResult GetVersionsByPeriodId(int entityId, int periodId)
        {
            var versionsInvoiceBillet = db.RemittanceInvoiceBilletVersionsCompacts
                .Where(x => x.LegalEntityId == entityId && x.PeriodId == periodId && x.IsCurrent && x.DownloadHash != null)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.LifePolicyNumber, x.LegalEntityGroupNumber }, 
                                    i => new { i.DownloadHash, i.FileTypeEnum, i.DueDate }, (key, group) => new
                {
                    LifePolicyNumber = key.LifePolicyNumber,
                    LegalEntityGroupNumber = key.LegalEntityGroupNumber,
                    Files = group.ToList()
                });

            return Ok(versionsInvoiceBillet.Select(x => new { 
                lifePolicyNumber = x.LifePolicyNumber,
                legalEntityGroupNumber = x.LegalEntityGroupNumber,
                invoiceAndBillet = x.Files.Select(f => new { 
                    downloadHash = f.DownloadHash,
                    fileTypeEnum = f.FileTypeEnum,
                    dueDatet = f.DueDate
                })
            }));
        }
```

If I try to call this method with Postman, the body comes empty. The problem is in invoiceAndBillet information that is returned, if I change to below, the body comes filled.

```
return Ok(versionsInvoiceBillet.Select(x => new { 
                lifePolicyNumber = x.LifePolicyNumber,
                legalEntityGroupNumber = x.LegalEntityGroupNumber,
                invoiceAndBillet = x.Files.Select
            }));
```

If I try to debug the selection that I'm trying to return, I get this message below:

[image]

Comment: have you check the data in debugger, is it really empty?

Comment: Yes, if I debug this block it give me a exception, but without much information, just says "The method or operation is not implemented."

Comment: Use try catch and see the exception

Comment: I tried but it doesn't go to the catch block, I posted the image in answers about the message that return from entity selection.

Comment: Do you have any `throw new NotImplementedException()` in your code? so you have to implement the methd you cant keep like thism it will always throw error

Comment: But If I remove the inner Select for Files, it works, I don't know if there is any rule about select inside select, because if I set  invoiceAndBillet = x.Files, it works.

Comment: Possibly the inner select is not supported and cannot be translated in the data access layer. You may want to try and do this in 2 steps. Set the working code to a local variable (the one that just uses the `invoiceAndBillet = x.Files`) and add a `.toList()`. Then in the 2nd step perform your inner select. The reason I'm suggesting this is so that the `toList()' will bring back the data from the data layer, then the 2nd step is just a Linq to Object query.